# Ant Design: input validation with Forms

Tags: reactjs, validation, antd, yup

I need input validation in app build with react and ant.design.
As I see from the ant documentation the way to validate input is to use Form tags.

I wonder is there any convenient way to integrate yup with ant.design library to have
the same validation results, like highlighting field with incorrect input, and write error message under it?

Or I just have to implement error displaying manually?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but did you check out this formik-antd library: https://github.com/jannikbuschke/formik-antdhttps://github.com/jannikbuschke/formik-antd?

Answer (score 2):

No need to use `yup` the antd validation is sufficient just you've to wrap your form with `Form` element that has prop named `form` that takes a value from `useForm` hook and add your validation rules in `rules` prop of `Form.Item` that could wrap any input element:

```
import { Form, Input, Button, Select } from 'antd';
const { Option } = Select;
....

const Demo = () => {
  const [form] = Form.useForm();

  
  return (
    <Form  form={form} >
      <Form.Item
        name="note"
        label="Note"
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
          },
        ]}
      >
        <Input />
      </Form.Item>
      .....
    </Form>
  );
};
```

for more details check [this](https://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-control-hooks)